# Rewrite regex without negation

Tags: regex, go, regex-negation

I have wrote this regex to help me extract some links from some text files:

`https?:\/\/(?:.(?!https?:\/\/))+$`

Because I am using golang/regexp lib, I'm not able to use it, due to my negation `(?!..`

What I would like to do with it, is to select all the text from the last occurance of http/https till the end.

```
sometextsometexhttp://websites.com/path/subpath/#query1sometexthttp://websites.com/path/subpath/#query2
```

=> Output: http://websites.com/path/subpath/#query2

Can anyone help me with a solution, I've spent several hours trying different ways of reproducing the same result with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
https?:[^:]*$
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dZ8wU9/2)

Comment: Thx for that, do you have any idea on how can I modify that regex so I can get the same selection, but until it finds &type=, or until the end if &type= not exists?

Comment: The regex will not work if the URL has `:` `http://websites.com/path/subpath/?q=tsid:51`

Comment: @alexsmn. Sorry, without using negation, this is the far I can get. Maybe some high-level user could help with those points.

Answer (score 2):

The lookaheads exist for a reason.

However, if you insist on a supposedly equivalent alternative, a general strategy you can use is:

```
(?!xyz)
```

is somewhat equivalent to:

```
$|[^x]|x(?:[^y]|$)|xy(?:[^z]|$)
```

With that said, hopefully I didn't make any mistakes:

```
https?:\/\/(?:$|(?:[^h]|$)|(?:h(?:[^t]|$))|(?:ht(?:[^t]|$))|(?:htt(?:[^p]|$))|(?:http(?:[^s:]|$))|(?:https?(?:[^:]|$))|(?:https?:(?:[^\/]|$))|(?:https?:\/(?:[^\/]|$)))*$
```