# Write regex without negations

Tags: regex, go, regex-negation

In a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832852/rewrite-regex-without-negation) I've asked for some help on rewriting a regex without negation

Starting regex:

```
https?:\/\/(?:.(?!https?:\/\/))+$
```

Ended up with:

```
https?:[^:]*$
```

This works fine but i've noticed that in case I will have `:` in my URL besides the `:` from http\s it will not select.

Here is a string which is not working:

```
sometextsometexhttp://websites.com/path/subpath/#query1sometexthttp://websites.com/path/subpath/:query2
```

You can notice the `:query2`

How can I modify the second regex listed here so it will select urls which contain `:`.

Expected output:

```
http://websites.com/path/subpath/cc:query2
```

Also I would like to select everything till the first occurance of `?=param`

Input:
   `sometextsometexhttp://websites.com/path/subpath/#query1sometexthttp://websites.com/path/subpath/cc:query2/text/?=param`

Output:

`http://websites.com/path/subpath/cc:query2/text/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a pity that Go regex does not support lookarounds. 
However, you can obtain the last link with a sort of a trick: match all possible links and other characters greedily and capture the last link with a capturing group:

```
^(?:https?://|.)*(https?://\S+?)(?:\?=|$)
```

Together with `\S*?` lazy whitespace matching, this also lets capture the link up to the `?=`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA7xX8/1) and [Go demo](http://play.golang.org/p/z-sTJHV61T)

```
var r = regexp.MustCompile(`^(?:https?://|.)*(https?://\S+?)(?:\?=|$)`)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", r.FindAllStringSubmatch("sometextsometexhttp://websites.com/path/subpath/#query1sometexthttp://websites.com/path/subpath/:query2", -1)[0][1])
fmt.Printf("%q\n", r.FindAllStringSubmatch("sometextsometexhttp://websites.com/path/subpath/#query1sometexthttp://websites.com/path/subpath/cc:query2/text/?=param", -1)[0][1])
```

Results:

```
"http://websites.com/path/subpath/:query2"
"http://websites.com/path/subpath/cc:query2/text/"
```

In case there can be spaces in the last link, use just `.+?`:

```
^(?:https?://|.)*(https?://.+?)(?:\?=|$)
```

Comment: Dude! You are awsome !!

Comment: When no overlapping matches are necessary and there is no look-around support there is always a way to get the required substring with the capturing regex feature.